# Kernel restarting when using sent2vec library

Tags: python, vectorization, restart

I am using the following code to test the library being imported. The "from sent2vec...." when kept is throwing the

```
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

I would appreciate your help so that I can move forward

```
from scipy import spatial
from sent2vec.vectorizer import Vectorizer


text = [
    "Running a test for the sentence vectorization",
]


print(text)
```

I checked the env and the sent2vec packages are installed. I was expecting the print to work so that I can move to next step for the Vectorization of the sentence.